# How to use the flag counter in a twig template of a node?

Tags: 8, theming, flags

The version dev of the module "Flag" for "Drupal 8" has added a new sub module "Flag Count":

https://www.drupal.org/project/flag/issues/2708291

I copied the code

```
{% set count = '[' ~ flagcount(flag, flaggable) ~ ']' %}
```

in flag.html.twig and I copy this file into the templates folder of my theme (I did not cache it).

But after I do not know how to do it. Currently to display the flag link in `node.html.twig` I put the following code :

```
{{ content.flag_like_node }}
```

How to add the number of flag ?

I tested the following code and none works

```
{{ content.flag_like_node_count }}
{{ content.flag_like_node.count }}
{{ count }}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will return an array of all the flag counts on a node:

```
\Drupal::service('flag.count')->getEntityFlagCounts($node)
```

(For all flags set for that node)
Via: https://www.drupal.org/node/2476349

You can use that in a preprocess function to get your flag counts and send it as a new variable to your template file. Like so:

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  $flag_counts = \Drupal::service('flag.count')->getEntityFlagCounts($node);
  $variables['like_count'] = $flag_counts['like'];

}
```

Then in your theme file you can output:

```
{{ like_count }}
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't ajax update when someone clicks the flag link. For that to work you have to put the count in the flag template.

Answer (score 2):

For flag count to make it work in AJAX workflow:

1. Use Dev version of Flag which has the flagcount function exposed to
   twig template.
2. In flag.html.twig Add: {% set count = flagcount(flag, flaggable) %}
3. use {{ count }} to display the counter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when this moved out of dev, but in 8.x-4.0-beta4 here's how you do it:

1. Copy flag.html.twig into wherever your theme's templates live
2. Add `{% set count = flagcount(flag, flaggable) %}` to it somewhere.
   Best place is probably right before the line that starts with `<div class="{{classes|join(' ')}}">`
3. Add `{{ count }}` after `{{ title }}` and span tag it, like this...

   ```
   <div class="{{classes|join(' ')}}"><a{{ attributes }}>{{ title }}<span>{{ count }}</span></a></div>
   ```
4. Flush caches

Comment: Worth noting: flag.html.twig will display the counter on every flag unless you put some logic in it to check for a particular flag. But the better method is to use template suggestions to rename flag.html.twig so it only applies to the appropriate flag. In my case, a comment with a flag called comment-upvote uses this template name: flag--comment-upvote.html.twig